Python PDF searcher overflows the RAM
As part of my program, I'm trying to use the pdfminer third-party library in Python to open and read the PDF pages, and then use regular expressions to search for specific patterns. I'm also using multiprocessing to parallelize this, because I have a large number of PDFs to analyze. Each process should be handling a single PDF.
I have this code to set up multiprocessing:
def process_theme_files(theme_dir: Path, processed_files: Optional[Set[str]] = None, theme_processed_files: Optional[Set[str]] = None) -> Tuple[List[Tuple[str, int, str, str, str, str, str, str]], List[Exception]]:
    """
    Processes files of a specific theme in a multiprocessed manner.

    Parameters:
    - theme_dir (Path): Path object pointing to the theme directory.
    - processed_files (set, optional): Set of globally processed files. Defaults to None.
    - theme_processed_files (set, optional): Set of files processed in the current theme. Defaults to None.

    Returns:
    - Tuple[List[Tuple[str, int, str, str, str, str, str, str]], List[Exception]]: A tuple containing a list of tuples
      containing extracted information from the theme files and a list of exceptions encountered during the processing.
    """
    results = []
    exceptions = []
    
    # Number of processes to be used (can be adjusted as needed)
    num_processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    # Initialize processed_files and theme_processed_files as empty sets if not provided
    if processed_files is None:
        processed_files = set()
    if theme_processed_files is None:
        theme_processed_files = set()

    # Get PDF files in the theme directory
    pdf_files = list(theme_dir.glob('**/*.pdf'))

    # Create progress bar
    with tqdm(total=len(pdf_files), desc='Processing PDFs', unit='file') as pbar:
        # Process PDF files in parallel using ProcessPoolExecutor
        with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_processes) as executor:
            # Map the process_file function to each PDF file in the list
            future_to_file = {executor.submit(process_file, pdf_file): pdf_file for pdf_file in pdf_files}
            
            # Iterate over results as they become available
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_file):
                pdf_file = future_to_file[future]
                try:
                    # Get the result of the task
                    file_results, file_exceptions = future.result()
                    # Extend the results list
                    results.extend(file_results)
                    # Append specific exceptions to the exceptions list
                    exceptions.extend(file_exceptions)
                except FileNotFoundError as fnfe:
                    exceptions.append(f"File not found: {fnfe.filename}")
                except Exception as e:
                    # Capture and log the generic exception
                    exceptions.append(f"Error processing file '{pdf_file}': {e}")
                
                # Update the progress bar
                pbar.update(1)

    return results, exceptions

And this code for processing individual files:
def process_file(file_path: Path):
    """
    Process a PDF file to extract text and information.

    Args:
    - file_path (Path): Path object representing the location of the PDF file.

    Returns:
    - Tuple[List, List]: A tuple containing two lists:
        1. List of extracted results.
        2. List of encountered exceptions during processing.

    Raises:
    - FileNotFoundError: If the specified file_path does not exist.
    - Exception: For any other unexpected errors during processing.
    """
    results = []        # List to store extracted information from each page
    exceptions = []     # List to store exceptions encountered during processing
    
    try:
        # Check the size of the PDF file
        pdf_size_bytes = os.path.getsize(file_path)
        pdf_size_mb = pdf_size_bytes / (1024 * 1024)
        
        # Check if the PDF file size exceeds the maximum allowed size
        if pdf_size_mb > MAX_PDF_SIZE_MB:
            exceptions.append((file_path, f"The file exceeds the maximum allowed size of {MAX_PDF_SIZE_MB} MB."))
            print(f'{file_path} - Exceeds maximum allowed size of {MAX_PDF_SIZE_MB} MB.')
            return results, exceptions

        # Open the PDF file and read its content into a BytesIO buffer
        with file_path.open('rb') as file:
            pdf_data_buffer = BytesIO(file.read())
            
            # Iterate through each page of the PDF
            for page_number, page in enumerate(PDFPage.get_pages(pdf_data_buffer, check_extractable=True)):
                # Extract text from the current page
                page_text = extract_text(pdf_data_buffer, page_numbers=[page_number])
                
                # Process the extracted text to extract information
                page_results, page_exceptions = extract_information(page_text, file_path.name, page_number + 1)  # Page numbers are 1-based
                
                # Extend results and exceptions lists with page-specific results and exceptions
                results.extend(page_results)
                exceptions.extend(page_exceptions)
    
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        # Handle case where the file does not exist
        exceptions.append(e)
        print(f"FileNotFoundError: {e}")
        raise
    
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle any other unexpected exceptions
        exceptions.append(e)
        print(f"Exception: {e}")
        raise
    
    return results, exceptions

The problem is that I run out of RAM, even with 32 GB installed:

Through my research, I learned that PDFs cannot be read randomly; they must be read sequentially from the beginning to the end of the file, which is how I implemented it.
Some of my PDFs are around 100 MB in size, never exceeding 200 MB, and some are quite long (1000 pages) with many images. Since I have to read all the pages when I process a PDF, the only workaround I could find was to limit the size of the PDFs I read to less than 100 MB. I also can't think of a way to restrict the page count - because to determine the number of pages, I need to open and read the file.
How can I limit RAM usage in this program?

@KJ I'm using Python because I'm collecting data from those PDFs. It's not about one sentence per file. I'm searching for some amount of information, such as article numbers, addresses and this kind of stuff. It's not about find one sentence within a great amount of PDFs. It's more like to gathering information over a collection of PDFs.

You appear to be using
pdfminer.
multiprogramming

I run out of RAM


How can I limit RAM usage in this program?

Your complaint is that your chosen degree of multiprogramming is too high.
So reduce it.
Run fewer concurrent instances.
You will want some measurements and estimates to assist with that.
pages from size
You may find it interesting to examine a sample of your PDFs and
estimate page count from file size,
coming up with a printed pages / megabyte conversion factor.
Sure, it will be inexact, but still informative.
memory footprint from size
Similarly, after a few runs you can estimate RAM consumption from file size.
Use psutil
to learn the OS-reported virtual memory size ("malloc size")
of a pdfminer child that processed a single PDF file.
Use that to relate file size to memory consumption.
It will be a noisy prediction.
If you're going to err, then err on the conservative side,
predicting a relatively large footprint.
>>> p = psutil.Process(child_pid)
>>>
>>> p.memory_info()
pmem(rss= ..., vms=67608576, ... )

Now sort the input PDFs by descending file size,
create a pool
with one or a couple of slots, and analyze all the big PDFs.
Ideally you will write all foo.pdf text to a foo.txt file,
which subsequent analysis steps can cheaply process.
Having dealt with the big ones, move on to process the medium sized
documents with a pool size of perhaps four.
Finally, use a larger pool to deal with all the small files.
The idea here is to never schedule more than your RAM can handle.
Start with a pool of just one worker, and make a baseline measurement.
Then verify that a pool of two workers actually goes faster, then three.
Stop when you see that additional concurrency is not improving elapsed
processing time.
We schedule big jobs first to avoid the situation where
a single core is working on a long straggler job
at the very end after all other cores have idled.
When short "easy" jobs are all that remain toward the end
of a run, it's likely that all cores go idle at roughly the same time.
make
The -j switch of GNU make offers a convenient way to schedule N concurrent
tasks, similar to python's multiprocessing pool size.
You might want to take advantage of it during interactive tests,
or during production runs.
